# Learn by themselves/on their own?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Please, which one is better?

Some people learn foreign languages by themselves/on their own?

Comment: Based only on this sentence, either is OK. Otherwise you need more context to decide.

Comment: What @user3169 said. HifaMo, you need to get used to the idea that almost anything can be expressed in many different ways in English, but that doesn't imply all the alternatives can be arranged on a scale of *worse -> better*, even in a specific context. For example, your own text could just as easily have included *"...learn **a** foreign language..."*, and I honestly doubt there could ever be a context where it would really be worth saying either the singular or the plural was "better".